# Spring thymeleaf give error in post request

Tags: java, spring, post, request, thymeleaf

I have this simple code: This is my controller class where i redirecting to a page

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {
    @GetMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public String viewInserisciUtente(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("nuovoUtente", new Utente());
        return "nuovo-utente";
    }

    @PostMapping("/nuovo-utente")
    public void memorizzaUtente(@ModelAttribute Utente utente){
        System.out.println(utente.getId());
    }
}
```

This is model class.

```
public class Utente {
    private String id=null;
    private String citta=null;
    private String genere=null;
    private String data_nascita=null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCitta() {
        return citta;
    }

    public void setCitta(String citta) {
        this.citta = citta;
    }

    public String getGenere() {
        return genere;
    }

    public void setGenere(String genere) {
        this.genere = genere;
    }

    public String getData_nascita() {
        return data_nascita;
    }

    public void setData_nascita(String data_nascita) {
        this.data_nascita = data_nascita;
    }
}
```

and My html page with thymeleaf is like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Inserisci un nuovo utente</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/nuovo-utente}" th:object="${nuovoUtente}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Città: <input type="text" th:field="*{citta}" /></p>
        <p>Genere: <input type="text" th:field="*{genere}" /></p>
        <p>Data nascita: <input type="text" th:field="*{data_nascita}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, as I said into the title, this simple code for a form give me error when I try to submit the form by post request. The error is the above:

```
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "nuovo-utente" - line 10, col 32)
```

What can you say to me? Some help will be appreciate

Comment: Did any of answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use diferent html and urls. One to create the form and another one to submit the form. You are using the same url.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your html page change

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

to

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And write your controller class like

```
@PostMapping("/nuovo-utente")
   public String memorizzaUtente(@ModelAttribute("nuovoUtente") Utente utente) {
      System.out.println(utente.getId());
      return "any page";
   }
}
```